# How to get value and Return values from Restlet?

Tags: java, web-services, restlet

I am using restlet in java. I want to send data to the restlet service and perform some operation on that and then return the result to the client, receive on client side.

I am not getting any tutorial for this.
Please can anybody provide me any example for this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am able to resolve this problem, from the help http://stackoverflow.com/a/7346548/1365080.  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Hello, World](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/firstSteps#part02) or [First steps](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.2/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet.html) can be helpful. Also, check out [REST for Java developers: Restlet for the weary](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2008/jw-12-rest-series-2.html?page=1), it demos an example application.

Comment: Thank You Max for your reply, I'll try this example.